# surjection from $\ell^1$ to $c^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Consider the map $S : \ell^1 \to c^*$ given by $S(y)=S_y$ where

> $$S_y(x)=y_1\lim_{i\to \infty}x_i+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_iy_{i+1} $$
> $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots) \in \ell^{1}$ and $x\in (c,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$, $c$ is the space of all convergent sequences. We need to prove that this map is a surjection.

**My attempt**: Denote $c_0$ as the space of all sequences converging to $0$, $x_0=\lim x_i$  and let $f\in c^*$. For $x=(x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty} \in c_0 $, $x = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_ie_i$ in sup norm, where $e_i$ has $1$ in $i$th coordinate and $0$ everywhere else. Then $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i f(e_i)$, and for the sequence $t= (t_1,\ldots,t_m,0,\ldots) \in c_0$ where $t_i$'s are such that $t_if(e_i) = |f(e_i)|$, we have $$f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}t_if(e_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}|f(e_i)| \le \|f\|_{op}$$ therefore, $y_0=(f(e_1),f(e_2),f(e_3),\ldots) \in \ell^1$. Let $T_y(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i y_i$ where $x \in c$ and $y \in \ell^1$. Clearly $T_y \in c^*$. Denote $a = (1,1,\ldots)$. Thus, for any $x \in c$, $$f(x)=f(x-x_0a+x_0a) = x_0f(a)+f(x-x_0a)=x_0f(a)+T_{y_0}(x-x_0a)$$
and $f(x) = x_0\big(f(a)-T_{y_0}(a)\big) + T_{y_0}(x) = S_{y}(x)$ for $y=\big(f(a)-T_{y_0}(a),y_0 \big) \in \ell^{1}$. Is this solution correct ?

Comment: I think my concluding line is incorrect.